# Cannot autoload class using composer from within other autoloaded class file

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I'm new to using composer for autoloading custom class files using 'PSR-0' way of autoloading classes.

Below is my directory tree structure.

[image: Folder Structure]

And below is my PSR-0 config in the composer.json file

[image]

Class autoloading is fine when requested from outside my project file after requiring the vendor/autoload.php

The problem is when trying to load a class from within another class with a defined namespace.

Example:

I am trying to call a static method **::GetDatabaseConfig()** from the **Config** class within the **Config** folder into the **Database** class within the **Database** folder.
This is the code I'm using inside the Database class.

***Database/Database.php***

```
namespace App\Database;
class Database{
    public static $con;
    public static $connected = false;
    public static $error = false;
    public static $error_message = "";

    function __construct( $opt=false ){
        $config = App\Config\Config::GetDatabaseConfig();
        //REST....
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work and displays this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Database\App\Config\Config" not found in /storage/emulated/0/code/durandal/htdocs/api/idan/App/Database/Database.php:13

I see that the namespace used in the Database.php file is used as a prefix when requesting App\Config\Config class.

What is it that I'm missing here? How to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using PSR-0 and not PSR-4 for any particular reason?

Comment: It's just that it forces me to stay strictly organised with my directory and file structure.

Comment: Why not properly import the classes using a `use` statement? If you want to skip the `use`, you have to use an **absolute** path to the class like `\App\Config\Config::GetDatabaseConfig` (with a backslash in the front)

Comment: Yup. That's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using a FQCN of the `Config` class, but a name relative to `App\Database` namespace.

To fix this, you need to prefix the `Config` class with a `\`:

```
\App\Config\Config::GetDatabaseConfig();
```

or even better, you can import the `Config` class with `use App\Config\Config;` and then use it with `Config::GetDatabaseConfig()`